# How can I disable eventHubs namespace?

Tags: azure-eventhub

How can I disable eventHubs namespace? I don´t want to receive charges from this service, because is only for test. And I don´t want to remove it

Answer (score 2):

There is no disable option for an Event Hubs namespace. However, you can export your namespace as an ARM template and delete the namespace after that. When you need it back, redeploy from previously exported template.

See more on export here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal